# Relationship Between Session, cookies and there behaviour

Tags: session, cookies, asp-classic

I am working on a project. After login i assign some value to session variable Like Session("userid")=XYZ. if i open any page inside application it will check for this value and if its not empty and has permission to access page i am allowing it.
Now if suppose i am accessing www.Domain.com/Pagename and close the tab and open the same link after copy paste it checks for session and it opens the same page which is absolutely fine.
But when i restart browser and try to open the page by link copy paste its throwing me back to login screen. Since Session is server side this should not happen. But i read on w3school that session is maintained using cookie, and cookie is lost after browser restart, so how can i maintain my session even after browser restart till it times out.It seems Both Session and cookie are contradicting each other. I didn't had this problem with similar code in asp.net application but in classic asp it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Seen this? : [Managing Sessions in ASP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms525445(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Session cookies are not designed to persist, if you want to do this store a value that identifies your user in some way that isn't obvious and easy to manipulate *(use a hash algorithm to generate a key that can be stored and compared against your database to find the user)*, then populate the `Session` with the required data to rebuild that users session and pass them through.